# Come to terms with

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Why do we use "come" after "have/has" in "to have come to terms with sth"?

Shouldn't we use "came" instead of "come" due to the present perfect grammatical structure?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not specific to the phrase "come to terms with". "Have come" is simply the correct past participle of "come": I come, I came, I have come.

- I come to terms with it.
- I came to terms with it.
- I have come to terms with it.
- I will have **to have come to terms with** it.